# Import error while using scikit-neuralnetwork

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.4 64 bit on windows 8

While trying to use the package scikit-neuralnetwork, this line of code raises the following exception:

```
from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer
```

I installed the GCC and g++ (4.8.1) compilers and added them correctly to PATH, however the following error continues to appear:

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to               execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to   Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this   warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
g++ -shared -g -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -    IC:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\include -o C:\Users\Mi\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_61_Stepping_4_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Mi\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_61_Stepping_4_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -LC:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\libs -LC:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3 -lpython34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 65, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 82, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\temp22.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sknn\mlp.py", line 17, in <module>
    import theano
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from theano.compile import \
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 18, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 568, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 117, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1989, in compile_str
    compile_stderr = decode(p_out[1])
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compat\__init__.py", line 35, in decode
    return x.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: A good advice: I struggled a lot with this kind of error message in Windows, the guys at theano constantly said, theano was made not for Windows rather for linux or mac. Thus I changed to linux and voila it worked. I wasted a lot of time with seeking some solution, no I'm happy to be here. :)

Comment: Problem is usually these problems are related to the compilers. I mean, I usually get into these problems when a compiler is needed, I install it, add it to path, it works with many other programs but not with the ones I actually need. Anyway thanks for the advice, will surely consider it when buying a new machine in the future.

Comment: That's right exactly what I said. I worked with theano under Windows a lot, but always happened something and always solved them some way with some smart hack, but I realized then that it costed more then I moved to Linux right away. And I was right. And it is faster too with the same machine...

Comment: Anyway I added two upvote for your struggeling. :))

Comment: Do you have Python2 installed on your machine by chance? I ask because it's usually the source of these 'utf-8' codec errors. Perhaps something is using Python 2 when you think it is using Python 3?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No, I am sure it is python 3. I double checked printing (sys.version)

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi thanks! :)

Comment: How did you install  scikit-neuralnetwork?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I think i used pip (it was this summer). The accepted answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is often solved by running the following, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html).

```
conda install mingw libpython
```

Since you've now installed your own installation of GCC, you may need to play around with environment variables, especially `PATH` to get things working.

Comment: I'll try running the command you suggested as soon as I get back. However, regarding the path, the compilers are already in path, I can run them from the command prompt by simply typing g++ or gcc. That's how I checked the version of the compilers installed.

Comment: I think Theano has a problem with some C++ compilers on Windows. It definitely works with MinGW but you'll need to be sure that MinGW is the first compiler in the `PATH`. The safest thing to do is probably uninstall GCC (and any manually added sections in the `PATH`, then install MinGW and libpython using `conda install`.

Comment: After some struggling, I cleaned my computer from all the compilers and finally installed the compiler using conda and it seems to work so far.. Thanks